# bootstrap 4 make alert appear on top of row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have an alert div and a row inside a container, when I close the alert the row content moves up. I want to make the alert appear over the row content so that when I close it nothing happens.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>TEXT</strong>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>

    <div class="row align-items-center">
        CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried in order to achieve this behavior? The code you've shown here merely illustrates the behavior you do not want.

Comment: I wanna fit the entire content of the page inside the viewport, when the alert is visible, it takes up space previously taken by the row content which makes the site content overflow the viewport and thus a scrollbar appears. I wanna make the the alert appear on top so that I the page's content always fits inside the viewport.

Comment: Why aren't you using the Bootstrap modal for this? Based on your description, it appears to be and do exactly what you want, no?

Comment: because I want to let the user choose to close it ot not, without affecting the visibility of the other elements in the page.

Comment: After reading your question and your first comment (several times), I still haven't got a clue as to what you actually want to achieve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muhammad's suggestion could be made to work if you set the container to position: relative;

```css
.container {position: relative;}

.alert {position: absolute; top: 0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-brand">Brand</div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Alerts</h2>
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
    <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery to change the visibility of the alert rather than it's display:

```
$('.alert').on('close.bs.alert', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden')
})
```

Here is a demo:
https://www.bootply.com/TazOvYZQyC

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing this is to add the following CSS:

```
position:absolute !important;
top:0px;
```

to the alert div.
Here is a sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Alerts</h2>
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" style="position: absolute; top:0px;">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
    <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that actually made the alert appear outside the container on top of the navbar.

Comment: change the css property "top" to the height of your nav bar.